# Can bigInteger be converted into string?

Tags: java, biginteger

Can I convert big Integer value into a string? and how? I know how to concatenate  Int into double, but not sure if I can concatenate integer into string.

Comment: Careful, Java is not the same thing (or even related to) JavaScript. I have edited your question tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most objects, including `Integer` and `BigInteger`, can be converted to a String using the [x.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method. If the value might be `null` you can use either `String.valueOf(x)` or `"" + x` The latter is slightly slower for the machine, but quicker and simpler for the developer IMHO.

The most notable exceptions are arrays, where I suggest you use the helper methods `Arrays.toString(array)` instead.

> not sure if I can concatenate integer into string

You can use `+` for concatenation. e.g.

```
String word = "hello ";
int n = 5;
String text = word + n; // String + int concatenation.
```

or

```
String text = "something";
text += " " + 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the trick in JavaScript:

```
var myString = myBigInt + '';
```

EDIT: The original question's language was changed from JavaScript to Java, so here's how to convert in Java:

```
BigInteger myBigInt = 10000000;
String myString = myBigInt.toString();
```

Here's a tutorial on [BigInteger.toString()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_tostring.htm).

Comment: @matthewherbst My answer was for JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: As the OP had wrongly tagged their question, this answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com;
   import java.math.BigInteger;
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String s=new BigInteger("100").toString();
    System.out.println(s);
    }
    }
```